# Eloquent, group a relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have got my main Location model, this model `hasMany` contact models. However the contact models need to be grouped by their type.

How would I go about doing this?

I have attempted to do a map on my Location's, however this doesn't appear to work.

```
$data = WebsiteLocation::query()
    ->where(['website_id' => $website['id']])
    ->orderBy('order')
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('vehicle_stock_location');

$primaryIndex = $data->map(function($location) {
    return (int)$location->primary_path === 1;
})->search(true) ?: array_keys($data->toArray())[0];

$data = $data->map(function($location) {
    $location->contact = $location->contact->groupBy('type');
    return $location;
});
```

This is my Location model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Locations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WebsiteLocation extends Model
{

    protected $with = [ 'contact' ];

    public function contact(){
        return $this->hasMany(WebsiteLocationContactDetails::class)->orderBy('order', 'type');
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

What i'm currently getting:

```
[
    0 => [
        'location_name' => 'test1',
        'contact' => [
            0 => [
                'type' => 'telephone',
                'content' => '000000'
            ],
            1 => [
                'type' => 'telephone',
                'content' => '004000'
            ],
            2 => [
                'type' => 'mobile',
                'content' => '000234'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'location_name' => 'test1',
        'contact' => [
            0 => [
                'type' => 'telephone',
                'content' => '000000'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

What I expect:

```
[
    0 => [
        'location_name' => 'test1',
        'contact' => [
            'telephone' => [
                0 => [
                    'type' => 'telephone',
                    'content' => '000000'
                ],
                1 => [
                    'type' => 'telephone',
                    'content' => '004000'
                ],
            ]
            'mobile' => [
                0 => [
                    'type' => 'mobile',
                    'content' => '000234'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'location_name' => 'test1',
        'contact' => [
            'telephone' => [
                0 => [
                    'type' => 'telephone',
                    'content' => '000000'
                ]
            ]           
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
<?php 
$data = WebsiteLocation::where(['website_id' => $website['id']])
    ->with('contacts')
    ->orderBy('order')
    ->get();

foreach($data as $record){
  $contacts = $record->contacts->groupBy('type);
}
```

Comment: I have got 2 telephone numbers, and 1 mobile on one of the location, the above code seems to remove one of the telephone numbers. Please see my updated post

Comment: I have ended up just using the relationships to get all of the contact types, and then getting the content details for them types, but thanks anyway